# Capistrano uses the wrong user to fetch remote repo. Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, capistrano, capistrano3

I've configured the public key on BitBucket and it works from SSH, but using Capistrano it defaults to the wrong user:

```
INFO [813163d1] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads \
 git@bitbucket.org:phec06/my-repo.git as **fedorius@localhost**
```

While it should be using user `ubuntu` as specified in `config/deploy/production.rb`:

```
server 'myserver.compute.amazonaws.com', user: 'ubuntu', roles: %w{app db web}
```

When I run:

```
cap production deploy
```

It gives me:

```
DEBUG [813163d1]    Permission denied (publickey).
DEBUG [813163d1]    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I've been searching for solutions to this all day and I'm new to Capistrano :(

Using Capistrano 3.6.1 with Rails 5, deploying to AWS Ubuntu using a Mac OS X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

Turns out I'm a little dumb. I started using `capistrano-scm-gitcopy` and gave up, but I left

```
set :scm, :gitcopy
```

On my `deploy.rb`, removing this line solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue on your bitbucket account or you are using wrong ssh-key for that account. Please double check that you were logged in as  `**fedorius@localhost**`. Try belows

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ssh -T hg@bitbucket.org
```

Comment: That is the problem, I'm *not* logged in as fedorius@localhost, but Capistrano tries to fetch from the remote as it, since this user doesn't exist (and of course doesn't have a ssh key) it fails.

Comment: btw the first command gives me

Agent pid 2112

But I don't think this is relevant